# How to hide the 'set' keyword in output while using set in python

Tags: python, comparison, set, python-2.x

Ok so I have two lists in python

```
a = ['bad', 'horrible']
b = ['bad', 'good']
```

I'm using the set operator to compare the two lists and give an output if a common word exists between the two sets.

```
print set(a) & set (b)
```

This gives the output as,

```
set(['bad'])
```

Is there anyway to remove the keyword 'set' in the output??

I want the output to look like

```
['bad']
```

Comment: Uhm, convert the output to list again? `print list(set(a) & set(b))`..

Comment: Do you need all common words or just one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply convert set to list:

```
list(set(['bad']))
```

Comment: @senderle Are you going to convert a set to a list to e.g. log it's contents?

Comment: @BasicWolf, well, the OP said nothing about logging. That _might_ be one rare instance in which performance trumps readability for this problem. But _even so_, this approach is still good. A quick test on my computer indicates that `str(list(s))` is 2-3x faster than using `', '.join(str(i) for i in x)` for small and large `s`!

Answer (score 2):

You can make a list out of it:

```
list(set(['bad']))
```

looks like

```
['bad']
```

Answer (score 1):

How about NOT creating a list to output a string, but just creating a string to be printed?

```
'[' + ', '.join(str(i) for i in your_set) + ']'
# or 
'[{}]'.format(', '.join(str(i) for i in your_set))
```

Comment: this is way too hacky and it looks bad!

Comment: What is exactly hacky here? This is normal Python, string formatting, string join() function, iterating over a set and converting each element to string.

Comment: The original question asked for quotes round the strings, so you may need to use `repr()` instead of `str()`, but that's why people are suggesting just casting to a list as the simplest way of getting what was requested. Your way would have been great if he just wanted a plain comma separated list of elements although in that case it would have been simpler just to do `', '.join(your_set)` as it was stated to already to be a set of strings.

Comment: While your code is indeed better **if the set is very large**, the `list()` solution is much more readable and thus better for small sets where the conversion overhead doesn't matter.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Agree. In a situation of quickly writing a small script I'd probably would do the same. About small sets: consider a situation, where there will be a 100K-iterations loop with short sets to be printed in a list-like format...